# Controlling a kiln with PID and old magnetic contactor

Tags: heat, pid-controller, contactor

I have retrofitted an old 240V/16A kiln with a controller consisting of an INKBIRD ITC-100VH, a FOTEK SSR-40 and K-type thermocouple in line with VegOilGuy's guide:

[image]
https://www.vegoilguy.co.uk/_maingifs/pid_diagram.jpg

My SSR has now failed (stuck in always on) so I want to replace the SSR with the kiln's original Yaskawa HI-A25 magnetic contactor.

I can't find any Yaskawa-specific documentation but I'm thinking that the Yaskawa design is not unique and A25 models from Hitachi and other manufacturers from that period are almost exactly the same.

[image]

Could someone with knowledge of these old style contactors tell me whether it could be controlled by my PID's AC250V/3A control voltage? If so, how would I wire it up?

Answer (score 0):

A contactor is always a contactor, it doesn't have to be old one. Usually the old ones are much expensive, since they are stocked for spare parts. The new/old contactor has to have a nominal current rating for the specified power and a coil for rated supply voltage and type (ac/dc).

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for the response. To clarify, the contractor is the original one that came with the kiln (the kiln is maybe 30-40 years old) and used to control the kiln using an old form of controller called a Kiln Sitter. So I know the contactor is the correct one for controlling my kiln elements, my question is whether my PID can operate the contactor with its channels 6 and 8 (which are AC250V/3A). I can't see on the contactor's label what the control voltage should be.

Comment: Some contactors can be fitted with a variety of coils. There is usually a marking somewhere that will tell you what voltage. It is likely to be the mains voltage of the unit.

Comment: @user301684 Assuming that contactor coil won't consume not even nearly 3A, then there should be no issues. But, the PWM period should be quite long i.e at least 10 seconds to avoid frequent turns on/off.  But you could also use some industrial SSR with proper heatsink,, rather than buying unknown stuff - this FOTEK SSR is the one largely counterfeited, there is no original one to compare with , they're all fake.